# play framework type mismatch; found : Int required: String

Tags: scala, playframework, compiler-errors, playframework-2.1

I am a beginner to Play framework and Scala, I'm trying to develop a simple web project with Play on Scala, I'm using the eclipse IDE!

My problem is when I change the parameter of a view template, despite the fact that I pass the "same new" parameter in the Action calling this view, I have an error like this:

```
type mismatch; found : Int required: String
```

To simplify, assuming we have a view that takes as parameter `@(value:String)` so I can call this view from an Action `Ok(html.say(value))` such as value is declared as String.

In this case, all is well!

But when I change the parameter of the view to take an Int `@(value:Int)` and I call this view from the Action with `Ok(html.say(value))` despite I changed the type of value from String to Int, I get:

```
Compilation error: type mismatch; found : Int required: String
```

I did a clean on the project but it didn't help. What is the problem?

Comment: This could either be a problem with Play or Scala IDE. Where do you see the error? In the browser when you refresh the page, or in Eclipse? Templates are compiled in a different manner to other standard code, so if it's the latter your IDE may just not be seeing the recompiled template.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the error appears in Eclipse!

Comment: Eclipse won't compile templates. Ignore its errors, specially when related to templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you compile from the Play console, either by typing `compile` or by reloading your page (when you are running the application). That will recompile the template. Then you can refresh Eclipse to make it pick up the changes.

Answer (score 2):

Before posting any questions on Play Framework "play clean compile" command should be run. It resolves 95% of such issues.